# sqlca.sqlerrm.sqlerrmc SQL code -284

Tags: c, db2, sqlcode

I am using embedded C:
the following query returns a strange SQLcode -284

```
  EXEC SQL
   select  *
   into    :xx
   from    xx
   where ....

if (SQLCODE < 0)
  { 
    err_log( "code %ld sqlerrmc %s",sqlca.sqlerrm.sqlerrml,sqlca.sqlerrm.sqlerrmc);
    db_error("");
    return -1;
  }
```

the error log was:
    code 4 sqlerrmc SQL **error -284** on line 2803

Could you please support me ?

Comment: EXEC SQL  //this is the line 2803

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [PostgreSQL Web site](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ecpg-errors.html#ECPG-SQLCA) describing the SQLCA:

> -284 (ECPG_INFORMIX_SUBSELECT_NOT_ONE)
> A result of the subquery is not single row (Informix compatibility mode). (SQLSTATE 21000)

I found this within two minutes of googling "PostgreSQL embedded sql -284".  I'd suggest you make more of an effort to find primary documentation such as this over asking the question on SO.

Comment: Is the clause **between** could be a SUBSELECT ?
the query is like that:
 select * into xx from xx where column1 = :vaulex and column2 between :value1 and :value2;

Comment: @ThesmartEagle: The problem is that your query is returning multiple rows, but you're writing to an object that can only store one rows' worth of data.  You either need to tighten your query so that it only returns a single row, or you need to use a cursor.